# Why does the following block of simple Java code (print Hello World ) raise compilation error?

Tags: java

This is a simple Java program within a Java file named HelloWorld.java. Apart from the HelloWorld class that has the main method, there is another class named generic that instantiates one HelloWorld object and calls a public method defined within the HelloWorld class. Why does this program not compile ?.

**Error says - [Syntax error on token "dummyMethod()", identifier expected after this token.]**

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Hello World !");

    }

    public HelloWorld() 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World Constructor !");
    }

    public void dummyMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("This method does nothing...");

    }

}

class generic 
{
       HelloWorld hw_object = new HelloWorld();
       hw_object.dummyMethod();
}
```

Comment: You cannot put code outside of a method like that.

Comment: You need define a method to execute statements.

Comment: you can define a variable but you cannot execute a method in the class scope. move hw_object.dummyMethod(); to a method.

Comment: `HelloWorld hw_object = new HelloWorld();` is defining and initializing a field - is valid outside a method. `hw_object.dummyMethod();` is just a statement - invalid outside a method

Comment: I agree to that. I removed the line [hw_object.dummyMethod()]... Now I expect the no argument constructor on HelloWorld class to be called and the output - "Hello World Constructor ! " to be printed.. Where am I going wrong with that ?. If the object instantiation within the class [generic] works then should the constructor not be called ?

Answer (score 5):

You can't just put code inside a class. It needs to be in a method.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello World !");

        HelloWorld hw_object = new HelloWorld();
        hw_object.dummyMethod();
    }

    public HelloWorld() 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World Constructor !");
    }

    public void dummyMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("This method does nothing...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this valid? `HelloWorld hw_object = new Test();`

Comment: I think you know it's not ;~p just a typo, fixed